# Get instagram photoes by tag wpf

Tags: c#, instagram-api

I am working with Instagram API and I found out that it has blocked `public_content` for developers. I have to pass my app registration, but they asks me for url of my site..., but I am creating desktop app! Maybe you know some other way to use this API? The users of my app can pass `AOuth`, but I can't find the way to do it. Also I tried to use InstaSharp, but it didn't help.

```
var clientID = "myid";
var clientSecret = "secret";

InstaSharp.InstagramConfig config = new 
InstaSharp.InstagramConfig(clientID, clientSecret);
OAuthResponse responses = new OAuthResponse();
var tags = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags(config, responses);
var result = await tags.Recent("inst");
foreach (InstaSharp.Models.Media item in result.Data)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.Link);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instagram offers a public search option that might be able to get what you want. I used Chrome and the Developer Console and the Network activity tab to decipher the proper query parameters.

```
https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch?context=user&q={username}
```

This will return a JSON result. This should be easy enough to search through if you're good with JSON.